# Android SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync Not Invoking OnMapReady

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, supportmapfragment

I am currently trying to set up an activity that uses a Google Maps fragment. This is not the main launcher activity, it is called from another activity when the user authenticates. The map shows fine and defaults to viewing Africa at a distance, however it does not move to my specified location in the OnMapReady function because that function is never called. I am invoking SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync, and I believe I have the correct permissions so I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Here is my `MapsActivity.java` file.

```
package com.dizydev.wayfare;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Here is my `activity_maps.xml` file.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dizydev.wayfare.MapsActivity" />
```

Here is my `AndroidManifests.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dizydev.wayfare">

    <!-- Meta Data -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Features -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is my `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dizydev.wayfare"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Again, the issue is that the OnMapReady function in my MapsActivity.java file is not being called. I have verified this by putting a logging statement in and it was never put out to LogCat. So if anyone knows why this might be happening I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Shouldn't Google API client be connected before you call  `mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);`?

Comment: Check Google Maps samples at https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials

Comment: My project seems to be an exact replica of that sample project. So I'm still not sure what the problem is

Comment: I just ran your code as-is, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Okay I switched the starting activity to be the MapsActivity and you're correct that it works. So the problem is now trying to get it to work when it is not the main activity.

Comment: _4 mins ago by [Ayush Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8258779/ayush-gupta)_ Where did you change the setContentView, in your main activity or in the MapsActivity?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out!

Apparently I needed to actually invoke the startActivity function to switch to a new activity instead of just setting the content view.

```
startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
```

It was previously this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```

This would not have invoked the MapsActivity.java file at all.